# Breaking up a 64 bit parameter in the macro definition

Tags: assembly, parameters, macros, arm, 64-bit

I am a beginner trying to write some ARM Assembly code.

I have a macro invocation like this :

```
STORE_VALUE 0x123456789ABCDEF0
```

I want the macro expansion of STORE_VALUE in this case to be:

```
MOV  x0, #0x1234000000000000
MOVK x0, #0x5678, LSL #32
MOVK x0, #0x9ABC, LSL #16
MOVK x0, #0xDEF0
```

I am not sure how to obtain 0x1234000000000000, 0x5678, 0x9ABC, 0xDEF0 from 0x123456789ABCDEF0. Can someone help me with the macro definition?

Comment: Depends on which assembler. Probably shifting and masking, but beware, that might only work for numeric constants.

Comment: I will be passing numeric constants only. I am using armasm.

Comment: I don't have `armasm`, but according to the manual, arithmetic operations using the normal `>>` and `&` operators should work.

Comment: I am getting a numeric overflow when I try to do a left shift by 32 bits                               MACRO
         STORE_VALUE $addr
         LCLA temp
    temp  SETA (($addr >> 32) & 0xFFFF0000)
    temp    SETA (temp << 32)
         MOV x0, #temp
         MEND

Comment: ["armasm does not support 64-bit arithmetic variables"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801e/dom1359731177128.html), followed by a recommendation against using armasm, rather sums things up, I would say...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how widely-supported it is across other toolchains, but the GNU assembler supports [specific relocations for `movz` and `movk`](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AArch64_002dRelocations.html#AArch64_002dRelocations), of the form `:abs_g*:` - for example:

```
.equ STORE_VALUE, 0x123456789ABCDEF0

movz  x0, #:abs_g3:STORE_VALUE
movk  x0, #:abs_g2_nc:STORE_VALUE
movk  x0, #:abs_g1_nc:STORE_VALUE
movk  x0, #:abs_g0_nc:STORE_VALUE
```

which, after a round trip via machine code, comes out looking like exactly what was asked for:

```
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   d2e24680        mov     x0, #0x1234000000000000         // #1311673391471656960
   4:   f2cacf00        movk    x0, #0x5678, lsl #32
   8:   f2b35780        movk    x0, #0x9abc, lsl #16
   c:   f29bde00        movk    x0, #0xdef0
```